# What is a difference between off-topic and migrated questions?

Tags: discussion, migration

I have seen some questions closed as off-topic and some question as off-topic migrated to other sites. What is the difference between migrated questions and off-topic questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two primary differences:

1. There might not actually be a site to migrate to
2. The question might not be of sufficient quality to justify migrating it, even if such a site existed. There's no point migrating a question that should/would get closed for quality issues on any site.

Additionally outside of a small set of other sites only moderators can action the migration, so there may well be some questions that meet all the conditions, but have been handled by the community and never seen by anyone with the access needed to migrate.

Comment: Your comment  "never seen by anyone with the access needed to migrate". Please explain!

Comment: Most moderation is community handled by design, but the community driven process doesn't have the same access as elected (diamond) moderators do. So moderators can make migrations to niche sites on the network which simply isn't an option available to many people reviewing questions.